# iOS 6 View gets small after opening the app on iOS 7

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, frame

I have view in my xib file whose height is 44 which contains buttons (like a toolbar).

It's working fine in iOS 7 now but when i open it in iOS 6 , the height of view gets small (24.0f) and so are the buttons in it.

Another thing is that, if i build the app with xcode 5 then the older versions of xcode will not be able to open xib files.

How to fix this issue? Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is works for me

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 00);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.origin.x);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"%f", self.view.frame.size.height);
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer of the second part of your question, the head of your xib file is different with XCode 5. But, with XCode 5 you can keep the old version of your xib using XCode 4.6 and iOS 6.

Go to your xib file and modify :

[image]

and use XCode 4.6 and iOS 6 :

[image]

With that, you can correct your bug with the 20px less in iOS 6.
You need to keep your xib file in iOS 6 and add a `Content View` below the view with a delta of 20px in Y and add your UI elements in this content view. like this :

[image]